# Como atrelar eventos a elementos dinamicamente criados e passar parâmetros?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Tenho uma tabela que é gerada via [ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax) e uma determinada coluna gera um link. Do jeito que foi implementado, atualmente, ele escreve um código [html](/questions/tagged/html) com [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) intrusivo. Algo como abaixo:

```
return "<a href=\"#\" id=\"detalhe-nota-" + record.data.id + "\" class=\'modal-detalhe-nota\' onclick=\"exibirModalDetalheNota(" + record.data.id + ")\">" + value + "</a>";
```

O [html](/questions/tagged/html) gerado sai algo do tipo:

```
<a href="#" id="detalhe-nota-80549984" onclick="exibirModalDetalheNota(80549984)">23628</a>
```

Eu gostaria de fazer o vínculo do evento `click` a este link pelo seu atributo id, porém como o id é dinâmico não sei como fazer. Uma solução alternativa com [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) seria usar a marcação [css](/questions/tagged/css) `modal-detalhe-nota`, como abaixo:

```
$(document).on("a.modal-detalhe-nota", "click", function(e) { });
```

Pelo que entendi pelos elementos serem criados dinamicamente, deveriam ter seus eventos vinculados dessa forma e não da forma abaixo:

```
$("a.modal-detalhe-nota").on("click", function(e) {});
```

Tenho duas dúvidas:

- Como fazer o vínculo do evento pelo atributo id?
- Como passar um parâmetro para a função? Pois este id que é gerado dinamicamente é parâmetro.

Comment: Já fiz algo do tipo. Lembro que na epoca eu usei somente o onclick passando o valor que eu precisava para o metodo. +1 boa pergunta.

Comment: @Marconi, eu estou procurando uma forma de fazer com javascript não intrusivo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a sua solução alternativa é possível. Esses ID podem ser adicionados com um atributo do tipo [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) onde `*` deve ser substituído por um nome.

Modifique o JavaScript que gera o link para:

```
return '<a href="#" data-detalhe-nota="' +
  record.data.id + '" class="modal-detalhe-nota">' +
  value + '</a>';
```

jQuery tem a função [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) que acessa os valores do atributos `data-*` diretamente, dessa forma não será necessário passar como parâmetro.

```
$(document).on("a.modal-detalhe-nota", "click", function(e) {
  var id = $(this).data('detalhe-nota'); // obter o ID
});
```

Comment: Sua resposta atendeu exatamente aquilo que eu precisava. A única diferença que montei a âncora via jQuery mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery é possível atribuir eventos a um elemento recém criado, mesmo que ainda não tenha sido inserido no `body`.

O que costumo fazer é criar esse elemento e, ao mesmo tempo, já atribuir seu evento pelo `jQuery`. Depois então posso adicioná-lo ao HTML.

Exemplo:

```
function criaLinkDinamico(callback, i) {

  var $link = $('<a/>', {
               'class' : 'minha-classe',
               'id' : 'meu-id-dinamico' + i
             });

 return $link.click(callback);

}
```

Daí poderia ser feito algo como:

```
 var links = [];

 for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

    var link = criaLinkDinamico(function ()
    { 
       console.log($(this).attr('id'));

    }, i));

    links.push(link);
 }

 $('html').append(links);
```

Na necessidade de passar um parâmetro para um elemento, você pode encapsular o callback.

Pequeno exemplo:

```js
function criarCallbackParametro(nome)
{
  return function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $('body').append(nome);
  }
}


$(function()
{
    $('#el-1').click(criarCallbackParametro('Wallace'));
  
    $('#el-2').click(criarCallbackParametro('Miguel'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="el-1">add Wallace</button>
<button id="el-2">add Miguel</button>
```

```
 $('.meu_elemento').click(criarCallbackParametro('wallace'));

 $('.meu_elemento').click(criarCallbackParametro('miguel'));
```

Comment: Só uma dica de desempenho, não utilize append, e outras funções que insiram valores no dom  dentro de um for, você irá acessar o dom toda vez, é melhor  armazenar o valor que irá para o dom concatenando e depois do for dar o append... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5925888/using-jquery-to-append-inside-a-loop-there-must-be-a-better-way

Comment: E caso a sua função callback precisa de parâmetro, como você faria?

Comment: É só um exemplo. Eu não vou ensinar boas práticas com jQuery porque não tenho tempo agora

Comment: Na resposta eu já postei o primeiro exemplo que mostra com utilização de callback. É só você ler direitinho. Não passei o `function` direto, mas declarei antes do `for`.

Comment: Sua solução me atendeu parcialmente, mas a solução abaixo foi a que resolveu meu problema efetivamente.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando tudo que você ja tem apenas realizando o `.on` dinâmico pelo `id`:

```
$('a[id^="detalhe-nota-"]').on('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var numberId = id.replace(/\D/i, '');
    callfunction(numberId);
});
```