# Exclusão de conteúdo com JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('<li>').dblclick(function(){

    var selfItem = $(this);
    selfItem.remove();

});
```

O código a cima não está funcionando. Quero que, ao clicar duas vezes, o próprio item seja removido, e, como uma otimização, queria colocar um código para que apenas os items dessa lista sejam removidos.

```
<div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="novo-item" id="nome-novo-item">
    <button id="lista-item">Cadastrar</button>
    <ul id="listagem-simples">
        <li>Avil</li>
        <li>Abocure</li>
        <li>Sodral</li>
        <li>Ulgran</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu código tem um erro. Você não deve usar `$('<li>')`, e sim `$('li')`.

Quando você usa `$('<li>')`, você está dizendo para o jQuery criar uma nova tag do tipo `li`.

No seu caso, se você quer trabalhar apenas nos itens `li` dentro de `#listagem-simples`, faça assim:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#listagem-simples').find('li').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <input type="text" name="novo-item" id="nome-novo-item">
    <button id="lista-item">Cadastrar</button>
    <ul id="listagem-simples">
        <li>Avil</li>
        <li>Abocure</li>
        <li>Sodral</li>
        <li>Ulgran</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Quando você utiliza `$('#listagem-simples')`, você está selecionando o elemento com esse `id`. Ao fazer um `find('li')` em seguida, você está procurando todas as `li` dentro desse elemento. Assim sendo, apenas os elementos ali dentro receberão essa função do jQuery.

Outra forma de fazer seria usando um seletor similar ao do Css3:

```
 $('#lista-simples > li').dblclick(function () {
     $(this).remove();
 });

 // ou ainda

 $('#lista-simples li').dblclick(function () {
     $(this).remove();
 });
```

No caso do seletor `#lista-simples > li` só será executada a função de `dblclick` caso o elemento `li` seja um filho imediado de `#lista-simples`. Já no segundo exemplo, o `#lista-simples li`, qualquer `li` que estiver dentro de `#lista-simples` vai ser afetada por `dblclick`.

Exemplo:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#pega-tudo li').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    $('#pega-filhos-imediatos > li').dblclick(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

});
```

```css
li { cursor:pointer};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="pega-tudo">
  <h3>todos</h3>
  <li>um</li>
  <li>dois</li>
  <ul>
      <li>um</li>
      <li>dois</li>
  </ul>
</ul>

<ul id="pega-filhos-imediatos">
  <h3>imediatos</h3>
  <li>um</li>
  <li>dois</li>
  <ul>
      <li>um</li>
      <li>dois</li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

## Atualização

Se você está tendo problemas com `li` adicionadas dinamicamente dentro de `#listagem-simples`, a minha sugestão é você utilizar o `on`.

Veja:

```
  $('#listagem-simples').on('dblclick', 'li', function () {
      $(this).remove();
  });
```

Aprenda mais sobre a atribuição de eventos a elementos dinâmicos aqui:

[Como atrelar eventos a elementos dinamicamente criados e passar parâmetros?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100365/como-atrelar-eventos-a-elementos-dinamicamente-criados-e-passar-par%C3%A2metros/100367#100367)

Comment: entendi, eu estranhei pq no processo de criação, ele funcionou com isso mesmo, mas obrigado por já explicar isso também  :D

Comment: Olha o exemplo de teste.

Comment: Podes usar `$('#listagem-simples li')` em vêz de `$('#listagem-simples').find('li')`. `+1`

Comment: então, eu consegui fazer excluir, porém, agora ele só exclui os itens que já vieram com a página, não exclui os novos

Comment: @Sergio adicionei isso à resposta. É que eu tenho mania de ir editando gradativamente...

Comment: @MuriloGambôa não falaste sobre isso na pergunta... que ias adicionar elementos dinamicamente... Testa assim: https://jsfiddle.net/vxfyz891/

Comment: é que eu já estava adicionando normalmente

Comment: @MuriloGambôa é que isso tem que estar na pergunta. Se você não especificar bem o que precisa, as respostas não irão realmente sair como você esperava. Você pode usar o exemplo do Sérgio, que vai funcionar.